# Unable to nominate more than one validator

Tags: polkadot, substrate-node-template, nominator

I am running a substrate based chain and tried to nominate 2 validators which were in the active state but it is only nominating one validator and showing an inactive status for the other validator. Can anyone help with this?

Nominator
[image: nominator]

Validators
[image: validators]

------------EDIT--------------

**Observations:**

- After waiting for many eras status of validators does not change.
- Increased the staking amount but still validating a single validator only.
- Algorithm is only selecting one validator per nominator for every era, even after nominating multiple validator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is meant to nominate only one validator as per [this](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-phragmen#rationale-for-minimizing-the-number-of-validators-per-nominator) document so that there would not be many transactions at a particular time, so not to populate the payout transactions.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://support.polkadot.network/support/solutions/articles/65000169209-what-does-active-inactive-waiting-mean-) it says that the "*validator election algorithm will **rotate** your stake among those validators on a **per-era basis**, so you may have a **different active validator** amongst your selected validators for each era, but you cannot choose which specific validator you will be actively nominating in a given era unless you are nominating just one validator*" (the 'active' validator).

It says that "*unless you are staking with a **considerable amount**, you will be nominating a **single** validator in **each era** with your **full stake***". This indicates that it might be possible to nominate more than one validator at a time in each era, such that they'd both be shown as 'active', but only if you were to try nominating with a considerable amount (a considerable amount that is larger than just 1000 5IRE). Otherwise, if 1000 5IRE isn't considered a considerable amount, then you will only be nominating a single validator that would be 'active' in each era with your full stake of 1000 5IRE.

If you nominated both of the validators with an amount that isn't considered a considerable amount then each era you will be actively nominating only a **single** validator with your full stake, so only one of them would be 'active', whilst the other one would be 'inactive'. Since you didn't nominate only one validator, you nominated both of them, the validator election algorithm will rotate your stake among those validators each era, so you may have a different 'active' validator each era. If you wait until a subsequent era do they rotate such that the 'active' validator becomes 'inactive' (whilst the 'inactive' validator becomes 'active')?

It also says that 'inactive' validators "*are in the active validator set and your list of nominations. However, you are not actively nominating them for this era (they are not active for you)*". So the reason why one of your validators is 'inactive' in that era is because you are not actively nominating them for that era.

Comment: What is considered as **considerable amount**, as for now minimum bond amount for nominators is zero so how much should i stake so that it is active for both validators.

Comment: it's not clear how much help you're after to be satisfied with a response. please update your question. have you tried staking considerably more with one account than the other, what did you observe? have you waited for a few eras to see if their active/inactive status changes, and what did you observe?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: I'm not sure what the **considerable amount** is, and I'm also not sure if I've misinterpreted that article and whether it's actually not even possible for a nominator to have two 'active' validators in a single era. Hopefully someone more knowledgeable can chip in with that information or guide us to where we'd find it in the source code, as I couldn't find it

Comment: Exactly i also didn't find anything in the source code, and got stuck here